# Read From Hexidimal Literal to String

Tags: c#, windows, emulation

Been working on a project that involves reading ROM headers (from the emulation scene) and reporting data. I've gotten most of it laid out, but having trouble finding the code to read from a hexadecimal literal address in the ROM (EX: 120h and then read "x" amount of bytes) (EX2: Some call to read 120h to 140h). I've tried looking on YouTube and googling it and no luck with it so far. Also, the language is C#.

Here is my code so far.

```
private void openROMToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select A ROM File";
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:/Users";
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    textBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName);
    textBox8.Text = "Calculating...";
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(OpenFileDialog1.FileName);
    }

    string getExt = Path.GetExtension(OpenFileDialog1.FileName);

    getExt = getExt.ToLower();

    if (getExt == ".smd" || getExt == ".gen" || getExt == ".md")
    {
       // SEGA GENESIS CODE (READ ROM DATA GOES HERE)
    }
    // REPEAT "if" STATEMENT FOR NEXT FILE FORMAT
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is ROM represented by a file in your project?

Comment: Yes. Its is pulled from a OpenDialoge box.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution I was looking for. I used this code.

```
// SEGA GENESIS CODE

      // ROM NAME 2

                BinaryReader br = new 
                BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(OpenFileDialog1.FileName));
                string romNameA = null;
                for (int i = 0x120; i <= 0x144; i++)
                {
                    br.BaseStream.Position = i;
                    romNameA += br.ReadByte().ToString("X2");
                    textBox4.Text = romNameA;
                }
                br.Close();
```

I now have the string of code I require. But now poses a possible new question I will ask in a new post.

Comment: You should to wrap the `BinaryReader` in an `using` block, to prevent exceptions stopping the handle being disposed.